# Use variables on grafana loki queries (LogQL)

Tags: grafana, grafana-variable, grafana-loki, promtail, logql

I have succesfully installed Loki on a server and Promtail on multiple hosts of my datacenter.
Each host runs a different number of tomcats, like tomcat10, tomcat11...tomcat20.

So on promtail, my job gets a label with the hostname and `__path__` is something like `work/java/tomcat*/logs*`.

Now I add on a Postgre the different appnames related to those tomcats, and the hosts and its names.

But I am struggling with the LogQL query on Grafana to access to those variables. For example, I define in Grafana the following variable named **varHost**

`select  server __value, server __text from loki_promtail.servers order by id ASC`

Let's say I want to access to every log on the Host *Saturn*. It's easy using `{job="saturn"}`, but instead of Saturn (which is the name of a host), I would like to use ${varHost} for doing so, so the same panel can show multiple host info.

On the same way, lets suppose I'm trying to access to `/work/java/tomcat10/logs/catalina.out`. I am expecting to be able to concat the varApp in the LogQL query, so, instead of
`{filename="/work/java/tomcat10/logs/catalina.out"}` I would like something like `{filename="/work/java/tomcat${varApp}/logs/catalina.out"}`, which I'm doing with a regex
`{filename=~"/work/java/tomcat${varApp}/logs/catalina.out"}` but fails when selecting **all** in the ${varApp} in Grafana.

How could I achieve that?

Thank u id advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the filename with the following LogQL:

```
{filename=~"/work/java/tomcat(${varApp:pipe})/logs/catalina.out"}
```

The ":pipe" modifier will change "$varApp" to 10|11|20, for example.

More info in the Grafana documentation [here](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/variables/advanced-variable-format-options/#pipe).

Comment: Thank u! That was awesome, didn't know about that pipe option!

Comment: Could you help me on the other problem I'm facing? I don't know why I do get a %0A (Line Feed) at the end of the query. This is my query:
`{job=~"${varServer}"}` 
and this is the error I'm facing on the query inspector
`"api/datasources/proxy/13/loki/api/v1/query_range?direction=BACKWARD&limit=1000&query=%7Bjob%3D~%22Saturn%0A%22%7D&start=1636515957302000000&end=1636537557302000000&step=15"`
I tried that without the %0A and works like a charm! That LF char, is it a thing of the DB or is it related to how I'm coding the variable in the query?

Comment: Great, could you accept the answer? I don't know about the %0A issue, are you using Windows?

Comment: Accepted!

Both Grafana and Postgre are installed on CentOS7, not Windows!

Comment: Was a data problem on DB, there were EOL on those variables. Changed them and now works like a charm!! Thank u!